# What is the difference between "Spread all Windows" and "Window Spread" in unity-tweak-tool?

Tags: terminology, unity-tweak-tool

I have Unity Tweak Tool v0.03 installed and it shows the options "Spread all Windows" and "Window Spread" in the Hotcorners section as different actions.

What is supposed to be the difference between these two options? For what I can tell, they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While both of them are almost similar, there is a subtle difference that makes them different.

"Window Spread" scales all open windows in a particular workspace. Whereas, "Spread all Windows" scales all open windows in all of the workspaces.